# Access Violation from Lambda occasionally exhibits itself

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a lambda that will occasionally cause an access violation when I try to erase an object from a `std::vector`. I pass a copy of the object to be deleted to the lambda instead of an iterator because the iterator may not point to the correct object come execution time.

Is there a better way to setup a lambda to remove a specific object from a vector? And what is the exact cause of the access violation here? Its difficult to debug as the local and auto variables are null/corrupted when I debug during this error.

```
... std::vector<CustomLayout> customLayouts; // private class member variable

void App::loadCustomLayouts() {
    CustomLayout customLayout;
    // ... create HWND

    onMessage(WM_RBUTTONDOWN, [customLayout, this]() {

        auto it = std::remove(customLayouts.begin(), customLayouts.end(), customLayout);
        customLayouts.erase(it); // occasionally causes access violation
    });
}
```

Comment: Try checking that `it != customLayouts.end()` before the erase. If it is, it means that `customLayout` was not found in `customLayouts`, which might give you a clue about the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are not following the proper `remove` idiom. It is simple:

```
vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), elem), vec.end());
```

You do not need to subtract anything or do any custom branches.

Answer (score 0):

std::remove return the end iterator of the range where all values equal to `customLayout` were removed. It actually does not remove anything, it just changes elements positions so that "removed" elements are placed after end iterator of the new range. Nevertheless, state of "removed" elements is unspecified and referencing them may cause problems.

Then, in terms of STL end iterator points at the element next to the last element of your range, not the last element itself. That's why any manipulations with end iterator (`it` in your case) are invalid.

The most probable error scenario is when `customLayouts`  does not contain elements equal to `customLayout`. Then `it` points to an element which never existed, and `erase` attempts to destroy it.

If you want to `erase` the last element of the new (shorter) range, you should write `customLayouts.erase(it - 1);`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I don't quite understand your solution part. If the cause is what you say, would something as simple as `if (it != customLayouts.end()) { customLayouts.erase(it-1); }` avoid/fix it?

Comment: @JakeM That should work, with the exception that you should elide the `-1`.

Comment: @JakeM It depends on what you are trying to achieve. You didn't write what object you want to remove, so I just pointed to the problem in your code as you asked. Probably the condition you wrote in the comment is not what you want to get, as it leaves last element of shorter vector untouched if nothing was erased. Try to draw your vector on a paper and manually "execute" the code by redrawing vector and crossing out unwanted elements. That should help to understand what you need.

Comment: The usual idiom without the `if` would be `customLayouts.erase(it, customLayouts.end());`.